# cant update with same code on Many To Many but did on One To Many. error is SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```php
Route::get('/update', function (){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $user->roles()->whereId(1)->update(['name'=>'Subscriber']);
});
```

Comment: Post the migrations or the table info

Comment: migration
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.   

2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.  

2019_07_06_153448_create_roles_table.  

2019_07_06_153928_create_role_user_table.

Comment: I mean the code inside those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use updateExistingPivot Eloquent Method
To update related Model
The Code will be like

```
Route::get('/update', function (){
    $user = User::findOrFail(1);
    $user->roles()-> updateExistingPivot(1, ['name'=>'Subscriber']);
});
```